# How to change the CommandLine of the PEB in an external running process

Tags: c#, windows, readprocessmemory

Basically I would like to be able to change the PEB of commandline, which I believe is at offset `0x70`. I am trying to do this using `WriteProcessMemory` which is part of `Kernel32.dll`.

```cs
Current_ImageBase.buffer = pNewAddr;
if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, rtlUserProcParamsAddress + 0x70, (IntPtr)(&Current_ImageBase), Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(UNICODE_STRING)), out intPtrOutput))
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Failed to reflect change back to PEB.\n");
    return false;
}
```

This should change the CommandLine of PEB.

Comment: - and what happens?

Comment: This bit `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(UNICODE_STRING))` looks really funky to me - can you explain?

Comment: Your belief seems unwarranted. Why do you think it's there -- and why do you think it's a good idea to assume it's there, when the location is an implementation detail that the kernel's free to renege on when it likes? What, ultimately, is this supposed to achieve at all?

Comment: Also, most apps that I am familiar with read/parse their command-line right after startup, and only then.

Comment: So basically it is for a "legacy" application we do not have the code base for. The Command Line contains sensitive information and we would like to "mask" it post launch. I relalise this is not ideal but its a temporary solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that the [PEB](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/blob/58825d4522f06986e09ab17b141204a66e68dd15/src/dbg/ntdll/ntdll.h#L2540) will be identical on every version of Windows.

The [PEB](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/blob/58825d4522f06986e09ab17b141204a66e68dd15/src/dbg/ntdll/ntdll.h#L2540) contains a pointer to a [_RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/blob/58825d4522f06986e09ab17b141204a66e68dd15/src/dbg/ntdll/ntdll.h#L2430) structure named ProcessParameters.

This structure contains a [UNICODE_STRING](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/blob/58825d4522f06986e09ab17b141204a66e68dd15/src/dbg/ntdll/ntdll.h#L167) named [CommandLine](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/blob/58825d4522f06986e09ab17b141204a66e68dd15/src/dbg/ntdll/ntdll.h#L2447).  Inside this structure is a pointer to a buffer which contains the command line arguments.

To externally overwrite these arguments, you must:

1. Call [NTQueryProcessInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess) to get the ProcessBasicInformation
   and therefore the PEB address
2. [OpenProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) and get write permissions
3. [ReadProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) the PEB
4. ReadProcessMemory PEB.ProcessParameters
5. ReadProcessMemory PEB.ProcessParameters.CommandLine
6. [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory) PEB.ProcessParameters.CommandLine.Buffer with the
   correct size pulled from the UNICODE_STRING.Length